# how to change text color of ListItem in night mode? (android studio)

Tags: xml

i am new to android programming.
i want to make text of list items color changeable by theme mode, when im using `<TextView/>` it runs succesfuly but it has a problem when i use that `TextView` in my custom list items and its color does not change.

i've added the `android:textColorPrimary` attribute to `themes.xml` and `themes.xml`(night mode) with colors of black and white and it worked in `TextView`.

this is my `activity_main.xml` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:padding="20sp">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

this is my `TextView.xml` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/item_style"
    android:text="@string/se"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:textSize="40sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textColor="?android:textColorPrimary"/>
```